# Running X program from SSH but using server's own X Display

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, x11, remote-access, remote-server

I would like to run a window/X program from SSH but using server's own X Display for the window rather than client's X Display. How to do that? Please not that I am not asking for X Forwarding here.

I tried this in SSh after connecting to server,

DISPLAY=:0.0

DISPLAY=:IP_I_dont_want_to_do_this because it might use public ip under-the-hood

What is the best way to do this?

For further information I am using Amazon EC2 Ubuntu instance.

Google suggest me "xpra", which looks "screen" for X window but I am intented to run application fully on X Display of the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to run a X client (e.g. xterm) under default Xserver like this

`DISPLAY=:0 xterm`

If above not works, try `ps aux|grep /usr/bin/X` to find which DISPLAY port your Xserver is using

Comment: Thanks! I was only trying 0.0 its 0:00 i.e. DISPLAY=:0:00 

However, I got other error if my application open more than one Off screening rendering windows. Still I accepted the answer because I assume that it is to do with assigning multiple display ports.

Comment: it would be very nice if the answer includes the whole command ;)